# UART Read problem from a TFT screen by usig PIC16F877A microcontroller

Tags: screen, microcontroller, pic, uart, lcd

I hope you are well. I am using a TFT screen that communicates through UART. This screen sends and receives data  by a known sequence in its datasheet. I used PIC16F877A to make an ISR function that reads data from it by adding each byte in an array, then the required byte is used for doing its function. The code did not run as expected.

The first problem is that the code runs properly after pressing reset button.

The second problem when I try to make bit shifting to add bytes together, I discover that the previous number is printed (i.e. if I write 125, 85 appears in the screen, which was the previous written number).

The third problem is that the UART ISR stops everything else just after it starts running.

Are there any solutions for these bugs?

This is the code:

```
int n = 0, flag = 0;
const int i = 12;
unsigned char* Read[i];
unsigned short up = 0, down = 0;
unsigned int max_value = 0;

//Timer 1 and UART ISR interrupt
void interrupt() {
    char buffer;
    unsigned char test;

    if (PIR1.RCIF == 1) {
        buffer = RCREG;
        Read[n] = buffer;
        n++;
        test = Read[0];
        if (test == 0xAA) {
            flag = 1;
        }
        PIR1.RCIF = 0;
    }

    if (TMR1IF_bit) { // If bit TMR1IF = 1
        cnt++;
        TMR1IF_bit = 0;
        TMR1H = 0x3C;
        TMR1L = 0xB0; // reset register TMR1
    }
}

void main() {
    TRISB.B2 = 0; // PortB2 is output
    PORTB.B2 = 0; // initial state is zero
    TRISC = 0x68;

    timer1init();     // timer 1 function
    UART1_Init(9600); // Uart baud at 115200
    Delay_ms(500);    // Wait for UART module to stabilize
    SPI1_Init();

    PIE1.RCIE = 1;    //enable receive interrupt
    INTCON.PEIE = 1;
    INTCON.GIE = 1;

    while (1) {  // Endless loop
        //UART Read value
        if (flag == 1) {
            up = Read[7];
            down = Read[8];
            max_value = ((down << 8) | up);
            HMT_WriteVPN16(0x080000, max_value);

            PORTB.B2 = 1;
            delay_ms(500);
            PORTB.B2 = 0;
            delay_ms(500);
            flag = 0;
            n = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which compiler? If it's xc8 your ISR looks strange.

Comment: What is the problem with your first problem? -- Would you mind to provide more context for the problems? -- Please provide a URL for the LCD's data sheet. -- Of course does everything else stop as long as the ISR runs. You have only one CPU. Or what do you mean in the third problem?

Comment: I am sorry mike. I missed to mention that i use MikroC

Comment: https://www.topwaydisplay.com/sites/default/files/2020-02/HMT050ATA-2C.pdf 

No. I mean that when the ISR runs, every process else freeze and do not continue work again

Answer (score 0):

1. problem 1 is not a problem. Everything is supposed to work properly after a reset
2. Since everything works properly after a reset, then it is possible your transmit buffers are not loaded with data in the right manner or loaded with appropriate data. Since you didn't provide your UART write code, it will be difficult to help you with this
3. That's the general nature of interrupts. Once an ISR starts, all other parts of the program will stop working.

However, your ISR seems to have a little problem because both conditions you are testing for may be true at the same time and this will give you some messy and inconsistent behavior. Replace your ISR with the following

```
  void interrupt() {
  char buffer;
  unsigned char test;

   if (PIR1.RCIF == 1) {
      buffer = RCREG;
      Read[n] = buffer;
      n++;
      test = Read[0];
      if (test == 0xAA) {
        flag = 1;
      }
    PIR1.RCIF = 0;
   }

   else if (TMR1IF_bit) { // If bit TMR1IF = 1
    cnt++;
    TMR1IF_bit = 0;
    TMR1H = 0x3C;
    TMR1L = 0xB0; // reset register TMR1
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am sorry that I could not comment lately. 
The program should work normally after power up, without the need of reset. 

About the UART write code, it is  stable function that works without any problem, and it does not affect the other parts of the program.

you are right about the function of the ISR, but to freeze everything and stop the program from continuing, this will need further investigation in the ISR structure.

Comment: Hi Ayman, sorry for my late reply. I’ve been very busy lately. I’ve edited my answer with the proper Interrupt function